# Firefox OS -> Why is Germany restricted (App submissions -> Regions and listings)

Tags: firefox, submission, firefox-os

[image: "Germany" is greyed out but I don't know why (FF OS, packaged App)]

Why is Germany restricted (App submissions -> Regions and listings).

Comment: Did you notice the link labeled "Learn why some regions are restricted"?

Comment: Yes it takes me to a page explaining why "Brazil" needs DEJUS ( https://developer.mozilla.org/Apps/Publishing/Marketplace_review_criteria#Content ). I have sent a mail to app-reviewers@mozilla.org for assistance.

Comment: Ratings have been improved today. All apps need to fill in IARC form. After I did that, I was able to unlock more countries, containing Germany and Brazil.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ratings have been improved today. All apps need to fill in IARC form (online, great integration). After I did that, I was able to unlock more countries, containing Germany and Brazil.

Answer (score 0):

Is your app a game by any chance? Some regions like Germany and Brazil need game apps to have ratings before they can be made public.

Mozilla is working to better integrate ratings, and the process required to secure them, into the submission flow.

Comment: Ratings have been improved today. All apps need to fill in IARC form. After I did that, I was able to unlock more countries, containing Germany.